# How to pass KonyMain.getActivityContext() from android for kony ffi

Tags: android, ffi, temenos-quantum

**Please check below code**

```
package com.firebaseio.httpsfirbasenosql.auth;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;

public class AuthClass {


    public static void callAuth(Context con, String url) {
        boolean isAppInstalled = appInstalledOrNot(con,"com.android.chrome");


        if(isAppInstalled) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
            try {
                con.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                // Chrome browser presumably not installed so allow user to choose instead
//                Log.i("Auth","ActivityNotFoundException");
                intent.setPackage(null);
                con.startActivity(intent);
            }

        } else {
//            Log.i("Auth","Application is not currently installed.");
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            con.startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    }

    private static boolean appInstalledOrNot(Context con, String uri) {

        PackageManager pm = con.getPackageManager();
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            return true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

From Kony App I called callAuth function with 2 parameters, 
1st argument is context and 2nd string.

Please help me how to app context from kony app or how to call kony context in android static class.

Comment: use `private static Context mContext = HealthApplication.getInstance()` in your `Application`: `public static HealthApplication getInstance() {
      
        if (null == instance) {
            instance = new HealthApplication();
        }
        return instance;
    }`

Comment: I did same thing and also create application class with extend application. code is working in android side, but when i tried to call from kony its give Exception

Comment: show your exception

Comment: UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
[exec-shell]        [dx] com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/firebaseio/httpsfirbasenosql/authResult compacted from 3424.4KiB to 2315.2KiB to save 1109.2KiB
[exec-shell]        [dx] Merged dex A (1527 defs/2788.7KiB) with dex B (4 defs/5.0KiB). R/AuthClass;
[exec-shell]        [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
[exec-shell]        [dx]     at

Comment: kony gave this exception

Comment: The exception show that `AuthClass ` has repeat.

Comment: you can modify your `AuthClass` packageName

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167237/discussion-between-abby-and-anuj-zunjarrao).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to pass the context. You can always get it using `KonyMain.getActivityContext()`. For this class, you must add konywidgets.jar to your build path or to the dependent libraries.
You can find this jar file in the following path : /temp//build/luaandroid/dist//libs